# Successor of @-moz-document url-prefix()

Tags: css, firefox

I tried to apply different style in Firefox using `@-moz-document url-prefix()`, but it's no longer support. How can I do it now?

Simple example:

HTML

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .test {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">asd</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FF V61 release channel and V59 Beta/Dev it was removed, the exception is the `url-prefix()` function, so your code should work, here is some info and code:

> The `@-moz-document` rule is no longer available from Web content since
>   it could be used by attackers for CSS injection to steal private data
>   in the URL of third-party sites. Firefox users are still able to use
>   this rule in the user stylesheet to personalize their browsing
>   experience.
>
> The at-rule support has already been removed from Nightly and early
>   Beta/DevEdition as of Firefox 59, and removed from all the channels
>   with Firefox 61.
>
> An exception is the **empty url-prefix** function that has been used as a
>   CSS hack targeting Firefox. It continues to be parsed on the Release
>   channel to avoid breakages but will be removed in the near future once
>   major compatibility issues are solved

[Source](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2018/moz-document-support-has-been-dropped-except-for-empty-url-prefix/)

In the current latest version (62.0.3) it still works, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwz7Lhrq/)

and using your snippet:

```css
.test{
  background-color: red;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix()  {
  .test {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

---

However, in the near future stops working, you can check all kind of browser hacks [here](http://browserhacks.com/), as you looking for firefox they are [here](http://browserhacks.com/#fx),

I would use this [hack](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-8e9b5504d9fda44ec75169381b3c3157): `@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) {}`

Using your snippet:

```css
.test{
  background-color: red;
}

@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar)  {
  .test {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank You! Can You tell me, how should I choose 'hack' in the http://browserhacks.com/ ? There are many options.

Comment: The one I choose here was taking in consideration that you were after CSS and not JS hack, then within CSS hacks I choose this  because it still has good old support FF16 and up (I don't see the need the for a hack to support eg: v3.6 and up), and then it was a clean rule not too complicated

Comment: Ok, I understand to specify: browser (FF) and content (CSS), but next I have to choose one of many types:  Selector Hacks / Media Query Hacks / Supports Hacks etc. Deeper there are some hard to understand options like: _::-moz-range-track, body:last-child .selector {} I feel confused, if You can write some additional advices, I will be grateful.

Comment: I've wrote it: `I choose this because it still has good old support FF16 and up (I don't see the need the for a hack to support eg: v3.6 and up), and then it was a clean rule not too complicated `